# How to generate SQL results to Excel sheet (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL developer. I need to export the SQL result set to Excel sheet. I know how to export it by manually.

Currently I am using a batch file. Which in turn run's multiple SQL script files. At the end there is a 1 SQL script which contains multiple SQL select statements. Now I need to export these result to excel sheet while running batch file itself.

Batch file Name: Mytest.SQL it contain multiple script files as below.

```
@@test1.sql;
@@test2.sql;
@@test3.sql;
@@test4.sql;
```

The last script test4.sql contains multiple select statements, which needs to be exported into multiple excels. Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Months ago I have found this solution. A ready to use package to unload query result into `xlsx` file, also with formating. Here is the link. There is also a description how to use the package.
[pl/sql package to unload as xlsx](https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/as_xlsx11.txt)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this VB-script, ie I run queries from Excel:

```
Set OraSession = CreateObject("OracleInProcServer.XOraSession")
Set ThisWorkbook.OraDatabase = OraSession.OpenDatabase(sDB$, sUSERID$, 0&)
Set OraDynaSet = ThisWorkbook.OraDatabase.CreateDynaset(QueryText, 0&)
```

You can in this macro calls a script and write cycle data in Excel

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a specific xls file or a csv file?

If you want a csv you can spool a file with sql.

For xls files, you can't do it easily, you'll probably have to go through another programming langage like java or c# or whatever with a specific library to build your report (e.g. for Java Apache POI).